# How to implement Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense filtering?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, add-on

I have developed my own language service for VS. Everything is fine IntelliSense (Word Completion) is working but I want to implement the new 2017 API - the filtering feature (http://developerpublish.com/how-to-turn-off-intellisense-filtering-in-visual-studio-2017/).
[image: IntelliSense]

I followed this walkthrough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/member-completion-in-a-legacy-language-service

but there is no word mentioning how to add filtering.

Is there any new doc (for VS 2017) or I am missing some class/parameter to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent example which demonstrates how the filtering can be achieved in modern VSs: https://github.com/madskristensen/EditorConfigLanguage >> https://github.com/madskristensen/EditorConfigLanguage/blob/d9aed6527e733bee5e9737e51b3571af0cbfb7be/src/Completion/CompletionSource.cs

The key is the **IIntellisenseFilter Interface** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iintellisensefilter?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

This interface works in Visual Studios 2015+, but as my extension is based on *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService* (because the extension supports Visual Studios 2005+) I could not find out how to integrate it.